# Flexbox в Safari с картинками не работает как в других браузерах

Tags: css, flexbox, safari

Задача: ряд картинок распределить по ширине контейнера. 
Делаю через flexbox. Во всех браузерах отображается как надо, т.е. картинки распределяются. В Сафари не работает - картинки сбиваются в левый угол и все. Читала про кроссбраузерность, дописала как надо с перфиксами. Не дает.
Это подвал с логотипами. Надо, чтобы во всех браузерах он выглядел одинаково.
Сафари не дает. И почему-то именно картинки.
Делала код с div-ами через flexbox, распределяет, работает в Сафари норм.
Картинки - нет. Это особенность браузера и я что-то не знаю, что дописать? Или просто ручки-крючки?
Код для основного блока:

```
.main_box {
width: 100%;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-align-content: center;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
        align-content: center;
-webkit-box-pack: justify;
-webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
        justify-content: space-between;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант дописать все свойства flex item-ов. Так как разные браузеры по дефолту используют разные значения.

```
img { 
   flex : 0 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: не помогло. А что должна давать эта запись?

Comment: flex-grow: 0
flex-shrink: 0
flex-basis: auto К сожалению у меня нет возможности протеститить в  safari ( Как вариант залейте код на codepen или прям в задачу через вставку кода. Только полностью. Мб найду ошибку.

Comment: Вот - https://codepen.io/CeReRa/pen/aYjPga   Собственно тут уже есть решение моей задачи.

Comment: решение там совсем не идеальное. В одном месте оно мне подходит. Но у меня есть целый ряд картинок (логотипы), который надо растянуть по ширине блока. Это решение их размещает не равномерно (что естественно).

Comment: Добро , обращайтесь если что)